# gnome-terminal: run a custom command without opening the terminal window

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am trying to use alacritty instead of the default gnome-terminal. When I specify it in "Profiles->Custom command" it does start, however the gnome-terminal also opens its own window in the background. Is there a way to get rid of this window? (Gnome 43.9, Debian 12)

Comment: Add `& killall gnome-terminal` to the end of the command.

Comment: Why do you run gnome-terminal if you don't want to have gnome-terminal? Don't run gnome-terminal, then. Run alacritty directly, not from gnome-terminal's custom command.

Comment: @egmont, I don't: it comes from nautilus' "Open in Terminal" menu. One can change that in its settings, but practically it still runs gnome-terminal-server which then runs the terminal emulator.that you specify. Thus is the question: how can one run it directly :) JayCravens, this would kill its child processes as well, including alcritty that I want running. I guess it would be possible to write a script that does something similar to what you suggest, but I am hoping for a simpler solution which does not create this problem in the first place...

Comment: Oh, I see. That menu entry is a plugin added by gnome-terminal, designed to specifically run gnome-terminal rather than an arbitrary application (such as another terminal). Probably something similar for Alacritty, or a generic one should be written. I'm afraid there's no ready solution. I've found gnome-terminal's custom command `sh -c 'setsid alacritty & sleep 1'` to somewhat do the job, but it's ugly and fragile (let alone the ephemeral gnome-terminal window, the increased startup time etc.). The proper direction would still be to avoid gnome-terminal altogether.